# Undefined reference to function of binary tree class C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am getting the following error:

```
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVDdszy.o:bt_test.cpp:(.text+0x4b7): undefined reference to `bt::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when trying to compile my bt_test.cpp to see if my binary tree is working how I want it to be. I have defined all of my functions for my binary tree class in the same header file, which I have seen to be a lot of other people's problems being that they defined their constructor in a file other than their header file, where the class was first created.

I can't seem to figure out why my linker is not able to reference my constructor as I have also recently created a queue class and implemented a constructor much like I am doing for my binary tree. Below is my following bt_test.cpp and my_bt_not_a_template.h files. Any help would be appreciated as to why this error is being thrown.

bt_test.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include "my_bt_not_a_template.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bt bt_1("t5");
    string lesse[5] = {"NAND", "NOT", "NOT","NOT","NOT"};
    int i = 0;
    while(!lesse[i].empty())
    {
        bt_1.insert(lesse[i]);
    }
    bt_1.printLevelOrder();

    return 0;
}
```

my_bt_not_a_template.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class bt
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        string value;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };
    node *root;
    void printLevelOrder_DO(node* rooto);

public:
    bt(string val)
    {
        root->value = val;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
    void insert(string val);
    node *search(string val, node *leaf);
    bool isEmpty() const {return root==NULL;}
    void insert(string val, set<string> inputs);
    node* search(string val);
    void printLevelOrder() {node* root; printLevelOrder_DO(root);}
    void printLevel(node* root, int level);
    int height(node* node);
};
void bt::insert(string val, set<string> inputs)
{
    node* nod = new node;
    node* parent;
    nod->value = val;
    nod->left = NULL;
    nod->right = NULL;
    parent = NULL;

    node* current;
    current = root;
    while(current)
    {
        parent = current;
        if(!(current->left && current->right))
        {
            //If both left and right are NULL
            //enter value into left leaf
            if(inputs.count(current->value) != 0)
            {
                //then is input and there should be no leafs containing anything below it
            }
            else
            {
                nod->left->value = val;
                nod->left->left = NULL;
                nod->left->right = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(current->value == "NOT")
            {
                nod->left->value = val;
                nod->left->left->left = NULL;
                nod->left->left->right = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                nod->right->value = val;
                nod->right->left = NULL;
                nod->right->right = NULL;   
            }
        }    
    }
}
...other functions defined
```

**EDIT:**
I realized I had two declarations for insert.

Comment: There's no definition of the `bt::insert` function in the code you posted. There's a *declaration* but no definition. Now maybe you have a definition in the code you omitted here '... other functions defined'. But if so then how can we help you with code you've omitted? If you do have a definition that you haven't yet shown us, then please post that definition. If you don't then there's nothing to explain, you simply haven't defined `bt::insert` as the linker is telling you.

Comment: Incidentally, when you do get things working, your main function contains an infinite loop.

Comment: @john wow, you're very right. I had kept reading that as a my constructor. Sorry, I've added my declaration of the insert function now

Comment: Well the definition for the `insert` that is missing, is the definition for the version that takes one string parameter. Incidentally you should not put out-of-class method defintions in a header file unless you use the `inline` keyword. Otherwise you risk *multiple* definitions if you include that header file more than once. But such a large function as that does not belong in a header file, put in in another cpp file. That's perfectly possible, and the correct thing to do, despite many newbies struggling with it the first time they try it.

Answer (score 0):

`bt(string val);`

You have an extra semicolon

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't gotten rid of that when I was uploading. I had redefined the constructor outside of the class in order to test if that might fix it and commented out the definition within the class. (it didn't fix it)